# ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException with Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm getting `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException` next to `String temp = word[5];` in my mapper.

I've researched this and I know what the error is coming from (when the input data is empty or the length is less or more than the index specified in the code. My data has some empty cell values)

I've tried to catch the array index error using the following code but it still gives me error.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;

public class AvgMaxTempMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {

  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, DoubleWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {


    String line = value.toString();

    if(line != null && !line.isEmpty() && str.matches(".*\\d+.*"));
        String [] word = line.split(",");
        String month = word[3];
        String temp = word[5];
        if (temp.length() > 1 && temp.length() < 5){
            Double avgtemp = Double.parseDouble(temp);


        output.collect(new Text(month),  new DoubleWritable(avgtemp));
    }
  }
}
```

If you could please give me any hints or tips to whether the error is in this code or I should look somewhere else, that would save a lot of stress!

Answer (score 0):

By throwing the exception in the method signature, you're basically causing the entire mapper to stop whenever it encounters a single "bad" line of data. What you actually want to do is have the mapper ignore that line of data but keep processing other lines.

You should check the length of `word[]` immediately after `split()`. If it's not long enough, stop processing that line. You'll also want to check that `month` and `temp` are valid after you've extracted them. How about:

```
String [] word = line.split(",");
if (word == null || word.length < 6) {
    break;
}

String month = word[3];
if (month != null) {
    break;
}

String temp = word[5];

if (temp != null && temp.length() > 1 && temp.length() < 5) {
    try {
        Double avgtemp = Double.parseDouble(temp);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        //Log that you've seen a dodgy temperature
        break;
    }
    output.collect(new Text(month), new DoubleWritable(avgtemp));
}
```

It's very important to validate data in MapReduce jobs, as you can never guarantee what you'll get as input.

You might also want to look at ApacheCommons `StringUtils` and `ArrayUtils` classes - they provide methods such as `StringUtils.isEmpty(temp)` and `ArrayUtils.isEmpty(word)` that will neaten up the above.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a custom counter instead, which you will increase every time you find an empty cell. This will give you a picture of how many such lines exist in your data. 
Along with some other efficiency modifications, my suggestion is the following:

```
import java.io.IOException;  //do you still need this?
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;

public class AvgMaxTempMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {

  public static enum STATS {MISSING_VALUE};
  private Text outKey = new Text();
  private DoubleWritable outValue = new DoubleWritable();      

  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, DoubleWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {


    String line = value.toString();

    if(line.matches(".*\\d+.*"));
        String [] word = line.split(",");
        if (word.length < 6) { //or whatever else you consider expected
            reporter.incrCounter(STATS.MISSING_VALUE,1); //you can also print/log an error message if you like                
            return;
        }
        String month = word[3];
        String temp = word[5];
        if (temp.length() > 1 && temp.length() < 5){
            Double avgtemp = Double.parseDouble(temp);                  
            outKey.set(month);
            outValue.set(avgtemp);
            output.collect(outKey, outValue);
        } //you were missing this '}'
    }
  }

}
```